# how to repeat shutting down and establish go routine?

Tags: go

every one,I am new to golang.I wanna get the data from log file generated by my application.cuz roll-back mechanism, I met some problem.For instance,my target log file is *chats.log*,it will be renamed to *chats.log.2018xxx* and a new *chats.log* will be created.so my go routine that read log file will fail to work.
so I need detect the change and shutdown the previous go routine and then establish the new go routine.

I looked for modules that can help me,and I found

```
func ExampleNewWatcher(fn string, createnoti chan string, wg sync.WaitGroup) {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()
    watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer watcher.Close()

    done := make(chan bool)
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            case event := <-watcher.Events:
                if event.Op == fsnotify.Create && event.Name==fn{
                        createnoti <- "has been created"
                }
            case err := <-watcher.Errors:
                log.Println("error:", err)
            }
        }
    }()

    err = watcher.Add("./")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    <-done
}
```

I use fsnotify to detech the change,and make sure the event of file is my log file,and then send some message to a channel.

this is my worker go routine:

```
func tailer(fn string,isfollow bool, outchan chan string, done <-chan interface{},wg sync.WaitGroup) error {
    wg.Add(1)
    defer wg.Done()
    _, err := os.Stat(fn)
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    t, err := tail.TailFile(fn, tail.Config{Follow:isfollow})
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }
    defer t.Stop()

    for line := range t.Lines{
        select{
        case outchan <- line.Text:
            case <- done:
                return nil
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

I using tail module to read the log file,and I add a done channel to it to shutdown the cycle(I don't know whether I put it in the right way)
And I will send every log content to a channel to consuming it.
So here is the question:how should I put it together?

ps: Actually,I can use some tool to do this job.like apache-flume,but all of those tools need dependency.
Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a complete example that reloads and rereads the file as it changes or gets deleted and recreated:

```
package main

import (
        "github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
)

const filename = "myfile.txt"

func ReadFile(filename string) string {
        data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filename)
        if err != nil {
                log.Println(err)
        }
        return string(data)
}

func main() {
        watcher, err := fsnotify.NewWatcher()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        defer watcher.Close()
        err = watcher.Add("./")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
        for {
                select {
                case event := <-watcher.Events:
                        if event.Op == fsnotify.Create && event.Name == filename {
                                log.Println(ReadFile(filename))
                        }
                case err := <-watcher.Errors:
                        log.Println("error:", err)
                }
        }
}
```

Note this doesn't require goroutines, channels or a WaitGroup. Better to keep things simple and reserve those for when they're actually needed.

Comment: Actually nothing. That was just copied over from the original example. Clearly the author did that to prevent the code from completing, as `<-done` is a blocking call and that keeps the `for` loop running and reading the file. However I'm going to update it to use a signal handler instead.

Comment: In that case why is there a goroutine there at all in the `ExampleNewWatcher` function.

Comment: Yes, I was going to say the author doesn't need a goroutine, channels, or a waitgroup as well. Better to keep it simple. However I didn't feel like rewriting the code to remove it earlier...

Comment: thanks for your time,cuz i wanna do multi jobs in codes later.When I read the source code of tail module.I found that there is reopen config will detect whether file is removed or deleted and try to reopen the file.And I wanna consult you for your advice that I put a done channel in tailer function.did I use it in right way?

Comment: @Rwang I don't think so, I think that will terminate the other `ExampleNewWatcher` goroutine, when you send the `done` signal, which looks like it would happen after the first edit. Don't you want to continue watching the file indefinitely? I also don't see why you need to tell the file watcher you've finished processing the file. It can just trigger the processing function, as I've demonstrated. Unless there are going to be multiple files changing within the directory that you want to watch, but then maybe I misread the question :)